# SHA1 is changed after I changed my laptop

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1

I have a running application in Play Store. I've tested and successfully updated my application three times. Suddenly, I had to change my laptop and reconfigured everything, i.e. Android Studio, JDK, SDK and everything. I knew that the signed key file is important for updating my application. So I backed up my project and the file.

Now I'm going to update my application again and I've noticed that my SHA1 key is changed. I cannot test my G+ login integrated with my app. I think that same problem will arise in GCM also. What should I do?

Comment: You are not signing with the same keystore as you did before.

Comment: When you say you can't test your app, do you mean in debug mode, not release mode?

Comment: I've attached my phone with my laptop. Then I've run my application from android studio. Now I cannot connect my G+ login.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson - Yes, I mean in debug mode, not release mode.

Comment: If it happens in debug mode is normal because it's not used the keystroke that you use to sign the app for the Play Store, unless you create one more signature and you configured the project to use that key to sign the app even in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store and its APIs were all given the SHA1 of the debug key from your original setup, and that's what it's still expecting.

The easiest thing to do, if possible, is copy the debug key from your old setup to your new setup and rebuild with it.  That file is in ~/.android/debug.keystore.

If you don't have your old key available any more, you will have to repeat the process you originally went through to connect your debug builds to whatever Google APIs you use.  But this time with the SHA1 of your new key to replace the old key that's no longer being used.

Answer (score 0):

You just need two steps to make your app up and working again:

1) Get your new SHA1 key.

2) Make the changes in the credentiials by going to console.developer.google.com where you have created the API key for signing your application.

Now how you are going to get the updated `SHA1` key, for that go to the android studio click on `View-> Tool Windows-> Gradle`. Open the file with your app name on it and "`(root)`" written next to it then go to Run Configurations and click on one of the file that you see. That's it you will get your new `SHA1` key and `MD5` there at the bottom where the configurations are executed.
Update your API key with this `SHA1` key and you are good to go!:)

**Note:** If you can't see the `SHA1` key then there is a button next to run button named "`Toggle tasks execution/text mode`" click on that and you will get the key.

[image: This is the button you need to toggle the output.]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when lost my old pc.
Your app is secure in google play store as the keystores.jks stores the original ShA-1 that identifies your app-identity. If you lost your keystores then you will face others problemas. Here we will resolve the different Sha-1 problem.
The problem you are facing is relative to the debug, as the sha-1 is generated from your pc and its not equal to the one you previously informed.
You need 3 steps:

STEP 1 - Get your new Sha-1.

-Get the path to your new key. Its is in: C:\Users\YOURUSER.android

- use this comand in terminal or command prompt -> keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\YOURUSER.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
- Copy the sha-1.

STEP 2 - Go to google developers console, find your credentials. Some of them are restricted. Enter in its properties and add the new SHA-1 in the list. Leave the old ones there too. Do it in every restricted credential.

STEP 3 - Go to your firebase console, settings. Then in Apps Android, just add the new SHA-1. This will make work.